# dynamically set select input value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, input

in a food truck app that I'm building, I have an order card component. On that order card component, it shows all the items that a user has in their order plus the count of each item. Where the count of each item is shown, I want to change that to render a select input where the default value of the select would be whatever count the user has already selected. I then want the user to be able to change the count using the select input.

Here is a screenshot of the component in the UI:
[image]

What I want to change to a select input is the count to the left of each item in the order. For example, the first item in this order is chicken tacos. The count is 2. I want a select input there to be set dynamically to 2 but then that the user be able to increase or decrease the count of chicken tacos in their order if they so choose.

Here is the code from the component:

```
const OrderCard = props => {
    const orderCount = props.order.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
        return prev + cur.count;
    }, 0);

    return (
        <Card className="order-card-main">
            <i class="far fa-times-circle" style={{ position: 'relative', left: '0px', textAlign: 'left', width: '100%', marginTop: '3%', fontSize: '1.5rem' }} onClick={() => props.closeOrderCard()}></i>

            <h1 className="order-card-title">Your Order</h1>
            <p className="order-card-truck">from <span className="truck-name">{props.selectedTruck.name}</span></p>

            <div className="order-items-cont">
                {props.order.map(item => (
                    <div className="order-item-div">
                        <p className="order-item-count">{item.count}</p>
                        <p className="order-item-name">{item.item}</p>
                        <p className="order-item-total">{CurrencyFormatter.format(item.total, { currency: 'USD' })}</p>
                        <hr />
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>

            <input className="order-note-input" type="text" placeholder="Note to truck..." />

            <button className="pay-button">
                <p className="total-items-count">{orderCount}</p>
                <p>Next step: pay</p>
                <p>{
                CurrencyFormatter.format(props.order.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
                    return prev + cur.total;
                }, 0), { currency: 'USD' })
                }</p>
            </button>
        </Card>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        selectedTruck: state.selectedTruck,
        order: state.order
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { closeOrderCard })(OrderCard);
```

It's been really hard to find examples of this by Googling. Please let me know if you need any more context/info and thanks in advance for your help.

UPDATE:

For those asking why a select and not a regular input, I am just copying this design from what is on Uber Eats. I may use the idea suggested but I still want to know how I would do this using a select input. Here is a screenshot of the order component from Uber Eats:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the use of a select instead of a simple input here, but you can still put your item.count inside and input, and trigger a method that edit your state on the 'onChange' event.

Comment: Agree with @QuentinGrisel, an input with type="number" will provide a numerical input a user *can* type in, but also provides a native increase/decrease button built in. Saves needing to populate a select's options.

Comment: @QuentinGrisel I updated my post to respond to your suggestion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your code modified with a select:

```
const OrderCard = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(props.order);

  const orderCount = props.order.reduce(function (prev, cur) {
    return prev + cur.count;
  }, 0);

  const displayOptions = (count) => {
    const options = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    return options.map((option) => (
      <option value={option} selected={option === count}>
        {option}
      </option>
    ));
  };

  const onSelectValueChange = (item) => {
    const selectedValue = document.getElementById('mySelect').value;
    // Do whatever you need with the value
    if(selectedValue === 0) {
      const newOrder = Object.assign({}, state); // better use deepclone() from lodash if you can
      for(let i = 0; i < newOrder.length; i++){
        const item = newOrder[i];

        if(item.id === item.id){
          newOrder.splice(i, 1);
          setState({...state, order: newOrder});
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <Card className='order-card-main'>
      <i
        class='far fa-times-circle'
        style={{
          position: 'relative',
          left: '0px',
          textAlign: 'left',
          width: '100%',
          marginTop: '3%',
          fontSize: '1.5rem',
        }}
        onClick={() => props.closeOrderCard()}
      ></i>

      <h1 className='order-card-title'>Your Order</h1>
      <p className='order-card-truck'>
        from <span className='truck-name'>{props.selectedTruck.name}</span>
      </p>

      <div className='order-items-cont'>
        {props.order.map((item) => (
          <div className='order-item-div'>
            <p className='order-item-count'>
              <select id='mySelect' onChange={() => onSelectValueChange(item)}>
                {displayOptions(item.count)}
              </select>
            </p>
            <p className='order-item-name'>{item.item}</p>
            <p className='order-item-total'>
              {CurrencyFormatter.format(item.total, { currency: 'USD' })}
            </p>
            <hr />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>

      <input
        className='order-note-input'
        type='text'
        placeholder='Note to truck...'
      />

      <button className='pay-button'>
        <p className='total-items-count'>{orderCount}</p>
        <p>Next step: pay</p>
        <p>
          {CurrencyFormatter.format(
            props.order.reduce(function (prev, cur) {
              return prev + cur.total;
            }, 0),
            { currency: 'USD' }
          )}
        </p>
      </button>
    </Card>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    selectedTruck: state.selectedTruck,
    order: state.order,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { closeOrderCard })(OrderCard);
```

I assume you know the possible options to put in your select, else you really should use an input type='number' with min/max value if needed.

**[Edit]:** I added the delete option you wanted though the selectedValue of the select. The principle is the same with a button.
I also assumed that you have a state with your order inside.

Comment: Yeah, I was gonna put up to like 12 in the select. I also want an option to remove the item entirely that would be the 0 index of the select.

Comment: That not really user friendly to delete the item when you select 0. you should add a button 'x' which trigger a method to delete the given item, let me edit the code to add this option

Comment: `const options = [...Array(12).keys()]` ;) and for UI/UX, that is up for opinion, but I think it is common to have both a remove button and a "confirm update" button.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the basic idea of what you're trying to do? I can add a bit more detail if it helps.
(It picks an option from the list using its index, so you may need to use the `indexOf` method first.)

```js
const select = document.getElementById("select");
select.selectedIndex = 1;
```

```html
<select id="select">
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
</select>
```

(Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)

Comment: Yes, I think this is along the lines of what I want to do.